# Assigning unique face id realtime

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

Im using the following code to generate each person an id. It works partially however the problem is that when more people comes in, each of them are getting the same id. Lets say if there are totally 3 persons, it is assigning the id 3 to everyone. I want it to be unique in incremental order. How can I sort this out?

```
 while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()

    input_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    detected = detector(input_img, 1)
    current_viewers = len(detected)
    if current_viewers > last_total_current_viewers:
        user_id += current_viewers - last_total_current_viewers
    last_total_current_viewers = current_viewers

    for i, d in enumerate(detected):
        x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(user_id), (x1, y1), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow("result", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)

    if key == 27:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code closely:

```
for i, d in enumerate(detected):
        x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(user_id), (x1, y1), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

`cv2.putText` is writing `user_id` on each of the rectangles that it is drawing.

Within the scope of the `for` loop, you're not updating the `user_id` parameter, hence the `for` loop is writing the same constant value on all the rectangles.

You should increment the value that you wish to see on the rectangle, **within this `for` loop itself.**

For example:

```
for i, d in enumerate(detected):
            x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, 'user_'+str(i), (x1, y1), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Now unlike `user_id`, the value `i` is incremented in every iteration of the `for` loop, hence `cv2.putText` will print the incremented value for each iteration, which should suffice your requirement

Comment: can you please eloborate?

Comment: however this will not count the person from morning till now

Comment: Agreed. This will work for the number of people in the current frame. You'll have to append this value to your count since morning